# Optimize Jedis usage experience via AOP?

Tags: java, redis, aop, jedis

I use Jedis to access our Redis service. My code is almost like that:

```
    public void doRedisOperations() {

        //redisOperator is a spring bean, it's acturally a redis connection pool, we must return jedis resources to this pool after we finished using it.
        Jedis jedis = redisOperator.getJedis();

        try{
            //jedis.doBlahBlah()...
        }
        catch (JedisConnectionException e){  //redis exception occurred
            redisOperator.returnBrokenJedis(jedis);
            jedis = null;
            logger.error("Redis exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(jedis!=null){
                redisOperator.returnJedis(jedis);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the try-catch-finally is boring. I want to change it via the AOP technical. My target is to write the code like that:

```
@JedisOperation
public void doRedisOperations() {
    Jedis jedis = redisOperator.getJedis();
    //jedis.doBlahBlah()...
}
```

Yes, maybe you find that it is quite similar to Spring's Transactional annotation. Is that possible? And how can I implement that?

Update:

I reviewed the latest Jedis library few minutes ago. I found that it's unnecessary to return the jedis object to the pool now, just close the it after finished using it. The code should be like this:

```
        public void doRedisOperations() {
        Jedis jedis = null;
        try{
            jedis = redisOperator.getJedis();
            //jedis.doBlahBlah()...
        }
        catch (JedisConnectionException e){  //redis exception occurred
            logger.error("Redis exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(jedis!=null){
                jedis.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest using the Spring Data Redis project... And use a `RedisTemplate` which already takes care of this for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I will try that.